# Need Assistance Implementing Transactions Into DataLibrary using ADO.NET AND Dapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, dapper

Download Code For Article Here:

CODE SAMPLE LINK REMOVED BUT SOLUTION STILL LEFT HERE IN CASE ANYONE ELSE NEEDS TO USE IT.

I am working on migrating over to a .net core web project using a DataLibrary with ADO.NET AND Dapper.  I have working copy in .NET framework, but I have pulled the nuts and bolts of original DataLibrary and I'm working to get a .net core project version up an running.

I have hit a wall when it come to integrating transactional functionality into the library with the new dependency injection system.  My DataLibrary works fine for basic CRUD operations, but I've yet to unlock the mystery on how to work the Transaction Logic into the new Library.

I'm not looking to use any other DB technologies like Entity Framework, I just need a nudge in the right direction on how to adapt my sample code project classes.  None of the samples I have found out there have been helpful yet.

Thanks in advance for any positive support the community can offer.

I attempted to integrate the IDBTransaction object into the code as I have in my sample and initialize it on the first call to Save method which passes in the bool flag on whether the operation should create a new connection or use the class library connection/transaction objects to make the calls.  If transactions were used to create the data, the developer would use the .Rollback() or .Commit() methods of the DBLibrary to commit or rollback the database calls.

The program just continuously fails on the var app = builder.Build(); in the Program.cs file of the web project because it doesn't know how to handle these IDBConnection and IDBTransaction objects in the transaction enabled version.

Comment: Seems weird to inject a transaction, I would expect the code to begin a transaction which then gets passed around. Can you add some code showing how your code works?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, so you should put some code in showing what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of just passing the IDBTransaction as a nullable parameter to each method call.  If the transaction != null, use the connection on it to run the query.  I just needed to create two versions of the method to call for SaveData() and LoadData().

```
public class SQLDB : IDataAccess
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public SQLDB(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string queryStoredProc, U parameters, CommandType commandTypeName, string connectionStringName)
    {
        string? connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

        IDbConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var rows = await c.QueryAsync<T>(queryStoredProc, parameters, commandType: commandTypeName);
        return rows.ToList();
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string queryStoredProc, U parameters, CommandType commandTypeName, IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        var rows = await transaction.Connection
            .QueryAsync<T>(queryStoredProc, parameters, commandType: commandTypeName, transaction: transaction);

        return rows.ToList();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveData<U>(string queryStoredProc, U parameters, CommandType commandTypeName, string connectionStringName)
    {
        string? connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

        IDbConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return await c.ExecuteAsync(queryStoredProc, parameters, commandType: commandTypeName);
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveData<U>(string queryStoredProc, U parameters, CommandType commandTypeName, IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        return await transaction.Connection
            .ExecuteAsync(queryStoredProc, parameters, commandType: commandTypeName, transaction: transaction);
    }
}
```

Now each data library call that references this just passes in the proper value based on it we are running a transaction or not.

```
public class SystemUserData : ISystemUserData
{
    private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;
    private readonly ConnectionStringData _connectionStringData;

    public SystemUserData(IDataAccess dataAccess, ConnectionStringData connectionStringData)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        _connectionStringData = connectionStringData;
    }

    public async Task<List<SystemUserModel>> Get(int? UID, IDbTransaction? transaction)
    {
        string where = UID.HasValue ? $"WHERE UID = {UID}" : "";

        if (transaction == null)
        {
            return await _dataAccess.LoadData<SystemUserModel, dynamic>
                ($"SELECT * FROM SystemUser {where};", new { },
                CommandType.Text, _connectionStringData.SQLConnectionName);
        }
        else
        {
            return await _dataAccess.LoadData<SystemUserModel, dynamic>
                ($"SELECT * FROM SystemUser {where};", new { },
                CommandType.Text, transaction);
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> Save(SystemUserModel model, IDbTransaction? transaction)
    {
        string scrubbed_name = model.Name.Replace("'", "''");
        string query = "INSERT INTO SystemUser (Name) VALUES ('@Name'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
        query = query.Replace("@Name", scrubbed_name);

        if (transaction == null)
        {
            return await _dataAccess.SaveData(query, new { }, CommandType.Text, _connectionStringData.SQLConnectionName);
        }
        else
        {

            return await _dataAccess.SaveData(query, new { }, CommandType.Text, transaction);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side notes: You need to dispose your `new SqlConnection` with `using`. Do **not** inject "scrubbed" data, it's dangerous, use proper parameters instead.